# Como fazer para uma <div> fechar quando for clicada fora dela?

Tags: jquery

> É possível fazer com que se a pessoa clicar fora de uma `div` que contém umas bandeiras ele feche automaticamente, mas se ele clicar dentro da `div` das bandeiras não aconteça nada?

OBS: Só se clicar fora da `div` que ela irá fechar.

```js
$('#global').on("click", function() {
    $('#paises').slideToggle(300);
});
```

```css
#paises{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="global">Tens bandeiras?</div>
<div id="paises">Tenho, bué da bandeiras, mas é assim, não sei onde meti os icons e então acabei por escrever um texto muito longo a dar conta que não sabia dos icons e nem sei se todos estão a ler isto até ao fim? Tu estás? É pá! Bora lá bater um papo...</div>
```

### [Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77dm6gk8/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para fechares o elemento quando ocorre um clique fora do mesmo, tens que estar atento a algumas coisas:

- O clique foi fora do elemento;
- O clique não foi no botão que controla o elemento;
- O clique foi fora do elemento e o elemento está aberto.

Tendo em conta isto, podemos estar à escuta dos cliques que ocorrem na pagina fazendo uso do método [`.mouseup()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) e assim despoletar uma verificação e fechar a `<div/>` se aplicavel:

Exemplo também no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wu9rwv3/).

```js
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var $div = $("#paises"),
        $btn = $("#global");

    // se o alvo do clique não é a DIV ou um filho da DIV
    if (!$div.is(e.target) && $div.has(e.target).length === 0) {

        // se o alvo não é o botão que abre/fecha a DIV
        if (!$btn.is(e.target) && $btn.has(e.target).length === 0) {

            // se a DIV está aberta
            if ($div.is(':visible')) {
                $div.slideToggle();
            }
        }
    }
});

$('#global').on("click", function() {
    $('#paises').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#paises{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="global">Tens bandeiras?</div>
<div id="paises">Tenho, bué da bandeiras, mas é assim, não sei onde meti os icons e então acabei por escrever um texto muito longo a dar conta que não sabia dos icons e nem sei se todos estão a ler isto até ao fim? Tu estás? É pá! Bora lá bater um papo...</div>
```

Comment: Os scripts que você coloca incorporado não funcionam porque você não habilita o jQuery :)

Comment: Tive que adaptalo novamente :) Veja: http://jsfiddle.net/77dm6gk8/2/

Comment: Obigado amigo! você é o cara.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Cá para mim é o StackFiddle que está quebrado! Porque dizes que "não habilito"?

Comment: Eu editei seu "StackFiddle" agora está funcionando corretamente. Eu setei o jQuery 2.1. Só falta um moderador aprovar. :)